# Refactor array of function values

Tags: php

I have the following code that contains too much duplication, and I want to simplify it. I am not a back-end dev and have rudimentary php skills, so I will appreciate any help:

```php
'gateways' => [
  'cod' => [
    'initializePayment' => function(OrderPage $virtualOrderPage): OrderPage {
      return $virtualOrderPage;
    },
    'completePayment' => function(OrderPage $virtualOrderPage, array $data): OrderPage {
      $virtualOrderPage->content()->update([
        'paymentComplete' => true,
        'payedDate' => date('c'),
      ]);

      return $virtualOrderPage;
    }
  ],
  'deposit' => [
    'initializePayment' => function(OrderPage $virtualOrderPage): OrderPage {
      return $virtualOrderPage;
    },
    'completePayment' => function(OrderPage $virtualOrderPage, array $data): OrderPage {
      $virtualOrderPage->content()->update([
        'paymentComplete' => true,
        'payedDate' => date('c'),
      ]);

      return $virtualOrderPage;
    }
  ],
],
```

Comment: If you have working code, and you just want to refactor it, then you should check whether your question would be better suited at Code Review StackExchange. It's not the kind of question we answer here - we tend to deal with more specific, tangible programming problems.

Comment: Is this array manually defined or built through a loop?

Comment: @ADyson It is working code. I didn't know about Code Review, thanks.

Comment: @El_Vanja The array is manually defined.

Answer (score 1):

Just pulling the arrayFunc out would clear code a bit

```
$arrayFunc = [
    'initializePayment' => function(OrderPage $virtualOrderPage): OrderPage {
        return $virtualOrderPage;
    },
    'completePayment' => function(OrderPage $virtualOrderPage, array $data): OrderPage {
        $virtualOrderPage->content()->update([
            'paymentComplete' => true,
            'payedDate' => date('c'),
        ]);
      
        return $virtualOrderPage;
    }
];

'gateways' => [
    'cod' => $arrayFunc,
    'deposit' => $arrayFunc,
```